# Using CodeIgniter, I tried making a .htaccess file and now my site redirects to something weird

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, apache2

www.mysite.com redirects to the right place, but mysite.com redirects to domain.ltd, which is nothing.  I have no idea why this is happening, and I can't get it to go away (even if I remove the .htaccess file completely...).  Does anyone have any idea what this might be?  Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Would probably need to see your .htaccess file and the VirtualHost section of the site's Apache config file, but I'm guessing you're seeing an ISP redirect because the mysite.com domain does not resolve correctly. Can you confirm that there is a valid A record pointing `mysite.com` to the same IP address as `www.mysite.com`?